# Why the main was returned value 3221225477?

Tags: memory

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    int m, n; cin >> m >> n;
    bool* b = new bool[n + 1];
    for (int i{2}; i < n + 1; i++) b[i] = true;
    b[0] = false; b[1] = false;
    for (int i{2}; i < n + 1; i++) {
        int c{0};
        if (!b[i]) continue;
        if (i > 1000) break;
        while (i * i + c * i <= n) {
            b[i * i + c * i] = false;
            c++;
        }
    }
    for (int i{m}; i < n + 1; i++) {
        if (b[i]) cout << i << '\n';
    }
    delete[] b;
}
```

This program is eratostenes sieve.
I input `1 100000`, then the main returned value 3221225477.
I think it is "access violation".
But I want to know the detail of it - why did it cause access violation.
I used Dev C++.

I want to recieve prime number in range of 1 to 100000.
But there was no output. and returned value 3221225477.